# Trying to set custom colours for a chart

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to add custom colours to a column chart, so each column has a different colour. I have the following code:

```
__this._chartColours = ['#2776BD', '#00A1D0','#00C195','#7ED321','#A8C600','#C9B600','#E3A600', '#F7941E', '#FC7149'];
__this._chart = am4core.create(__this._tileChartDiv[0], am4charts.XYChart);

if(result.chartDataMap != null)
{
    var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
    var counter = 0;
    $.each(result.chartDataMap, function(xAxis, yAxis)
    {
        __this._dataProvider.push({"category": xAxis, "column-1": yAxis});
        __this._chart.colors.list.push(am4core.color(__this._chartColours[counter]));
    });
    __this._chart.data = __this._dataProvider;
    __this._chart.padding(40, 40, 40, 40);
    
    var categoryAxis = __this._chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;
    categoryAxis.title.text = result.xAxisTitle;

    var label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
    label.wrap = true;
    label.maxWidth = 120;

    var valueAxis = __this._chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.title.text = result.yAxisTitle;

    var series = __this._chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
    series.dataFields.valueY = "column-1";
    series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}"
    series.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 0;

    __this._chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
}
```

It renders the chart fine based on the dataprovider I create but it is not setting the colors. I got the colours code from here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/. The XY Chart and derivative charts section

I tried to use a theme, but that didn't work either:

```
function am4themes_myTheme(target) 
{
    if (target instanceof am4core.ColorSet) 
    {
        $.each(__this._chartColours, function(index, item)
        {
            target.list.push(am4core.color(item));
        });                   
    }
}

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_myTheme);
```

It sets all the columns to the first colour. Then I tried adding a color property to the dataProvider for each column but again it sets them all to have the first colour.

I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

First, if you want the chart to use *only* your colors, instead of appending to the default chart's `ColorSet`, you have to [manually override it](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/colors/#XY_Chart_and_derivative_charts) by assigning an array of `Color`s to `chart.colors.list` (instead of `push`ing values to it).

Next, the column's color (`fill`) by default is based on its series. So even if you populate the chart's `ColorSet`, it's only each new series that will get a different color, not each column.

To set an individual column's color it would be something like:

```js
column.fill = am4core.color("#2776BD");
```

To get each column to have its own color, we can set that upon the column's first instantiation, i.e. on its [`template`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/)'s [`inited`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/column/#inited_event) [event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/). Further, a column's `dataItem` will have a property/reference to its `index`, so we can use that with [`ColorSet`'s `getIndex` method](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/colorset/#getIndex_method) to assign colors in sequence.

So your final code might look something like this:

```js
__this._chart.colors.list = [
  am4core.color("#2776BD"),
  am4core.color("#00A1D0"),
  am4core.color("#00C195"),
  am4core.color("#7ED321"),
  am4core.color("#A8C600"),
  am4core.color("#C9B600"),
  am4core.color("#E3A600"),
  am4core.color("#F7941E"),
  am4core.color("#FC7149")
];
series.columns.template.events.once("inited", function(event){
  event.target.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(event.target.dataItem.index);
});
```

Here's a fork of our [Simple Column Chart demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/) with the above code and your custom colors:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/2ef06f392b347412c61bcdcd3439a5c6